# Pass radio button value through address bar/URL

Tags: url, radio-button

I have to interface with a page that I haven't built, so this is a bit trickier than it would be if I could simply pass the information through via code.

Basically, I need to link to [this page](http://www.regonline.ca/Register/Checkin.aspx?EventID=1057346#pageContent) using one of three different buttons.  Each button refers to a different radio button.  Adding in the page anchor was easy enough, but I would like to do the same by selecting the respective radio button for the link clicked.  Is this even possible through the URL itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't directly affect the selection of radio buttons on that site using URL since this page uses POST method for transferring form data, look at the html code:

```
  <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
```

in order to do the thing you want, you need to reproduce this form on your page.